# Is "which I thought was strange that" incorrect grammar?

Tags: grammar

From "The Craft of Family Therapy" by Salvador Minuchin, etc.:

> The therapist says to a family:
>   "So you gave birth to a genius?" The family agreed, which I thought was strange that a child so young could have so much influence.

I suspect the sentence is grammatically wrong.
Thanks for response.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that it's ungrammatical. People do say this kind of thing, but it's a mistake when they do.

You can say:

> The family agreed, which I thought was strange.

This sentence has a non-restrictive relative clause modifying a finite proposition (*The family agreed*). Let's rearrange the sentence so that it has no relative clause:

> I thought [that the family agreed was strange].

The clause *that the family agreed was strange* can usually be rearranged with an extraposed declarative finite clause (also possible is infinitival *for the family to agree*), and expletive *it* occupying the position normally reserved for the subject:

> (I thought) it was strange that the family agreed.

Now consider the competing pair of clauses:

> That a child so young could have so much influence was strange.

and...

> It was strange that a child so young could have so much influence.

The writer has embedded in a relative clause a clause with **strange**, forgetting that the argument of **strange** is already in the main clause. 
A clause based on **strange** can have both extraposed subject and canonically-ordered versions, but the extraposed form is more frequent. In experience you expect to see an extraposed subject after **strange**, so the mistake is understandable.

Comment: How about if there's a comma or a dash after *strange*, so that the complement clause becomes something akin to an appositive clause clarifying what the *which* refers to? Is it perhaps more of a punctuation error?

Comment: @Araucaria I don't think so. it is not going to be grammatical unless the reader can know what is supposed to be strange: the family's agreement with the therapist's statement, or the child's influence.

Comment: @Araucaria also you don't see *which* being used to introduce a non-subordinate clause in standard written English. and if you do (in casual speech and dialect), the clause is a complete clause, not a relative clause with a "gap" in it, as in the OP's sentence.

Comment: It seems to me that if the sentences run: *"So you gave birth to a genius?" The family agreed, which I thought was strange - that a child so young could have so much influence*. then the agreeing and the child having so much influence would being portrayed as part of the same phenomenon. I don't see why this construction makes the relative clause a non-subordinate clause?

Comment: @Araucaria I guess I can see the interpretation and bracketing you are suggesting. the fact that the family agrees with the statement is part of the child's influence. if you squint as you suggest, i could see the sentence becoming passable.